# wire to board connector for 10 wires

Tags: header

I was looking for a quick way of attaching 10 wires to a [PCB Header](http://uk.farnell.com/amphenol/t821110a1s100ceu/header-vertical-2-54mm-10way/dp/2215304?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-acce#anchorTechnicalDOCS). This is for a production job of 50 units at a time, the header style/ design is fixed. Three components are to be attached to the header, 1 x 2 wire solenoid and 2 x 4 wire sensors.

From what I can tell the options are using barrel crimps with a connector or an  [IDC Receptacle](http://uk.farnell.com/amphenol/t812110a100ceu/socket-idc-2-54mm-10way/dp/2215232?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-acce).

I would ideally like to use an IDC but have found that it is tricky to align each wire correctly, probably why they're mainly used for ribbon cables...

Crimping 10 individual wires seems time consuming but is looking like the only viable way. Would appreciate some recommendations / alternatives.

Comment: Why not use an IDC ribbon cable? Simple to make and generally very reliable.

Comment: @Steve Even not to make but find in nearly any electronic junk.

Comment: @SteveG sorry I forgot to add this header is used for connector three separate components to the main board. 2 wire solenoid, and 2, 4 wire sensors.

Comment: YOu want a 2x5 crimp housing with crimps, for example https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0022552101/WM2522-ND/171966 With the proper tools, the crimping and crimp insertion is not as bad as you think.

Comment: Does anything in [here](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?key=wire_to_board_connectors&channel=PRODUCTS&langPref=english) turn your crank?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Wondering why this was closed so quickly. It does not appear to be soliciting a product but a technology. Granted the answers might be specific product examples, but the question is still good from a design point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is to crimp the ends of the wired onto barrel housings and insert them into appropriate housings. With the appropriate tools it's not as time consuming or as difficult as you may imagine with practice.

[image]

[image]

[Example shown](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0022552101/WM2522-ND/171966) is a Molex offering. House PN#:0022552101, 24-30AWG Crimp PN#:16-02-0069

Comment: What's nice about this is that it is not only sound, but viable from first prototype all the way to production, since you can eventually buy the components with the contacts already crimped, or buy single-ended pre-crimpled leads if the parts don't already have leads, or even have the entire cable assembly fabricated.